# GeoCoordinate in C#

Tags: c#, location

`f_lat` should return with value of customer latitude,but there is a mistake somewhere so it returns 1(return 1 is not expected result).

The coordinates of customer and drivers returns correctly from database.

When I put `return f_lat;` before `GeoCoordinate` constructor,it returns correct latitude of customer,but I put after `GeoCoordinate` constructor,it returns wrong latitude of customer.

Who can help to me?

```
[WebMethod]
public double FindNearestTaxiDriver(string f_mobilephone)
{


    double f_lat = 0.0;
    double f_lng = 0.0;

    ArrayList d_mobilephone = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList d_lat = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList d_lng = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList distanceBetweenTwoPoints = new ArrayList();

    MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString());
    MySqlCommand f_mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select f_lat,f_lng from farecoordinates where f_mobilephone='" + f_mobilephone + "'",mySqlConnection);
    MySqlCommand d_mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select d_mobilephone,d_lat,d_lng from drivercoordinates", mySqlConnection);

    try
    {
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = f_mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            f_lat = Convert.ToDouble(mySqlDataReader["f_lat"].ToString());
            f_lng = Convert.ToDouble(mySqlDataReader["f_lng"].ToString());
        }

        mySqlDataReader.Dispose();

        mySqlDataReader = d_mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            d_mobilephone.Add(mySqlDataReader["d_mobilephone"].ToString());
            d_lat.Add(Convert.ToDouble(mySqlDataReader["d_lat"].ToString()));
            d_lng.Add(Convert.ToDouble(mySqlDataReader["d_lng"].ToString()));
        }
        GeoCoordinate f_coordinates = new GeoCoordinate(f_lat, f_lng);
        GeoCoordinate d_coordinates = new GeoCoordinate();

        for (int i = 0; i < d_mobilephone.Count; i++)
        {
            d_coordinates.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(d_lat[i]);
            d_coordinates.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(d_lng[i]);

            distanceBetweenTwoPoints.Add(f_coordinates.GetDistanceTo(d_coordinates));
        }
        //distanceBetweenTwoPoints.Sort();
        return f_lat;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        return 1.0;
    }
    finally
    {
        f_mySqlCommand.Dispose();
        mySqlConnection.Dispose();
        mySqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the catch exception is being hit. Try using `catch(Exception exception)` instead of just ignoring the exception with `catch(Exception)`. Then, put a break point at the line `return 1.0;` and see what exception was generated by looking at the `exception` variable

Comment: Wait, are you asking us to find the error that's causing your exception, or to troubleshoot your geolocation logic or both?

Comment: yeah,i am asking what is exception,when i wrote manually values of parameters of GeoCoordinate constructor,it runs correctly,but when i make dynamically values of parameters of GeoCoordinate constructor,it runs wrong.For example; use GeoCoordinate f_coordinates = new GeoCoordinate(25.21, 12.36); no problems but use GeoCoordinate f_coordinates = new GeoCoordinate(f_lat, f_lng); there is a problem